# Slide In Animation Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a menu I a am working on that is supposed to slide in from the right. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="slide-in">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="item"> Option 1</li>
    <li class="item"> Option 2</li>
</ul>
```

I am using CSS (SCSS) and jQuery to handle the animation by adding a .active class

The CSS:

```
.slide-in {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin: {

        top: 27px;
    }
    .menu {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-top: 25px;

        list-style: none;
        .item {
            padding-right: 25px;
            font-size: 26px;
            text-align: right;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
            &:first-child {
                 border-top: 1px solid #222;
            }
       }
    }
    // Animation
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    transform: translateX(300%);
    .active {
        transform: translateX(0%);
     }
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('.hamburger').click(function(){
    $('.meat').toggleClass('active');
    $('.hamburger').toggleClass('active');
    $('.slide-in').toggleClass('active');
});
```

The problem is that the `transform: translateX();` on `.slide-in.active {}` doesn't seem to work. In essence, the `.slide-in` box should start to the right of the screen, and then when a button is pressed, it will move into place. The box is currently sitting 300% to the right of my screen, and just won't move back into place.

*Note:* I am trying to avoid using `@keyframes` for compatibility's sake.

What I've got on codepen: http://codepen.io/pcmckinstry/pen/OWLQeZ

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I simply forgot a `&` in the middle of the animation code.